# How to write multiple values to on a row to txt and avoid tuple?

Tags: python

I would like to write three values on a row in my txt.

My function:

```py
def write_txt(file_name: str, content: str) -> None:
    with open(file_name, "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(content + "\n")
```

But when I insert multiple values into a `content` (as a tuple) like this:
`write_txt("myfile.txt",f"{int(value[0]),int(value[1]),int(value[2])}")` I got this in my txt:

```
(594940819, 1, 0)
(594940820, 1, 1)
(594940822, 1, 1)
```

But desired output is this:

```
594940819,1,0
594940820,1,1
594940822,1,1
```

How can I do this without using multiple replace? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your input:
`write_txt("myfile.txt",f"{int(value[0]),int(value[1]),int(value[2])}")`
here you are passing the string `f"{int(value[0]),int(value[1]),int(value[2])}"` that evaluates as a tuple since you have put commas. Correct text:
`f"{int(value[0])},{int(value[1])},{int(value[2])}"`
Correct statement:

```
write_txt("myfile.txt",f"{int(value[0])},{int(value[1])},{int(value[2])}")
```

Answer (score 3):

`str.join` is perfect for this, just make sure you convert everything in content to a string before joining:

```
>>> content = (594940819, 1, 0)
>>> content_str = map(str, content)
>>> line = ",".join(content_str) + "\n"
>>> print(line)
594940819,1,0
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using tuple itself, you should have tried using `join` function on the tuple and a few other functions:

```py
tupleToString = ",".join(map(str, yourTuple)) + "\n"
```

Note that, in order to pass the data to `join` function, you need to transform the element from `int` to `str`. We achieve this goal using a map function which transforms the value into a string then pass this map object to the join function.

Comment: But *content* is a *str* !

Comment: @ArthurKing Yes, you are right, I didn't pay attention to the `str` type in the function. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1):

`{int(value[0]),int(value[1]),int(value[2])}` is a tuple. You can rather pass the correct string representation:

```
f"{int(value[0])},{int(value[1])},{int(value[2])}"
```